SharePoint online multi line text field limit larger than documentation
I have list on SharePoint online containing a multi line text field. According to the documentation found here the limit of this field is 63999 characters. I noticed that I can store more than the limit. I can even paste 500k characters and the listitem still saves and can be edited. Is there a risk storing more content than the 63999 limit?

The documentation indicates that the limit for a multi-line text field in SharePoint is typically 63,999 characters. However, you can store more than this limit. Just as SharePoint has a limit of 5000 List View Threshold, but you can store more than 5000 items.
Reference:https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/list-view-threshold-in-sharepoint-online-faq.html
Storing more content than the documented limit could pose risks, such as potential performance issues, data integrity concerns, or unexpected behavior during data retrieval or manipulation. It's generally advisable to adhere to documented limits to ensure optimal performance and compatibility with SharePoint features.

Thanks for your answer. Its about 5000 List View Threshold. I understand that. My question is about the multi line textfield limit.
